How to compure Elliptic function using complex integral and Cauchy principal value
I integral the elliptic function in complex plane when $1<Re[z]\le k^{-1}$:
$F(z)=\int_0^z\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-k^2u^2}\sqrt{1-u^2}}(0<k<1)$
Since the integrand has a singularity at (u = 1), we must make the integration path avoid it. Because we require (z) to fall in the first quadrant, we reasonably require that when the integration path is near (u = 1), it passes through the upper half-plane. Using Cauchy's theorem, we transform the integration path into $0\rightarrow 1-\delta \underrightarrow{*}1+\delta \rightarrow z$, where the path at the * is a semicircle in the upper half-plane. When the radius of the semicircular path tends to zero, why does the intergal of the semicircular path tends to 0 as well?
I have tried it by using the residue thm @ u = 1 and the $Res(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2u^2}\sqrt{1-u^2}},u=1)=0$ implies the integral is zero.
However, I cannot show it by using polar form: let $u=1+\delta e^{i\theta}$ while $\theta \in (0,\pi) $ and in this way the integral becomes:
$F(z)=\int_0^z\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-k^2u^2}\sqrt{1-u^2}}=lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{i\delta e^{i\theta}d\theta}{\sqrt{1-k^2(1+\delta e^{i\theta})^2}\sqrt{1-(1+\delta e^{i\theta})^2}}\le\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|i\delta e^{i\theta}|d\theta}{|\sqrt{1-k^2(1+\delta e^{i\theta})^2}\sqrt{1-(1+\delta e^{i\theta})^2}|}=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\delta d\theta}{|\sqrt{1-k^2(1+\delta e^{i\theta})^2}\sqrt{1-(1+\delta e^{i\theta})^2}|}$.
Now the problem becomes how to prove that the integrand is convergent as $\delta \rightarrow 0$. I am stuck here.
